# angularjs map directive for openlayers does not get scope value

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I want to create an angular map directive for [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/) map application. For example this is an [example of map](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/accessible.html).

I created an angularjs directive.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("my.map").directive("map", [mapDirective]);

    function mapDirective() {
        return {
            "template": "<div id='map' style='width: 400px; height: 300px'></div>",            
            "link": function (scope) {              

                var map = new ol.Map({
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: [0, 0],
                        zoom: 1
                    }),
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    target: "map"
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

This sample works fine. But I hard coded the map element id name. And I want to get `id` value from scope.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("my.map").directive("map", [mapDirective]);

    function mapDirective() {
        return {
            "template": "<div id='{{target}}' style='width: 400px; height: 300px'></div>",
            "scope": {
                "target": "@"
            },
            "link": function (scope) {

                var target = scope.target ? scope.target: "map";

                var map = new ol.Map({
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: [0, 0],
                        zoom: 1
                    }),
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    target: target
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

But this does not show the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openlayers map target property [accepts 3 types](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html): Element | string | undefined.

Sou you can set the target as element[0]

But you set directive parameter `replace:true`, so map changes with directive.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("my.map").directive("map", [mapDirective]);

    function mapDirective() {
        return {
            "template": "<div style='width: 400px; height: 300px'></div>",
            "replace": true,
            "scope": {

            },
            "link": function (scope) {

                var target = scope.target ? scope.target: "map";

                var map = new ol.Map({
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: [0, 0],
                        zoom: 1
                    }),
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    target: element[0]
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the value is not bound to the scope or the map is not rendering? I tried to reproduce in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8DNrm3?p=preview) but this seems to work as expected.

**HTML**

```
<map target="{{id}}"></map>
```

**Directive**

```
 template: '<div id="{{target}}" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">{{target}}</div>',
 scope: {
    "target": "@"
 },
 link: function (scope) {
 }
```